# Javascript - access specific part of Object conditionally

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a specific part of an object conditionally based on a passed parameter.

**The object has a structure similar to this:**

```
const obj = {
  a: [
    { value1: "a11", value2: "a12" },
    { value1: "a21", value2: "a22" },
    { value1: "a31", value2: "a32" }
  ],
  b: [
    { value1: "b11", value2: "b12" },
    { value1: "b21", value2: "b22" },
    { value1: "b31", value2: "b32" }
  ]
};
```

In the app there is a function needing either the values within a or within b depending on what is passed to the function:

**Function:**

```
// AorB is a string which is either "a" or "b", but could be anything else if this doesn't work

const myFunction = (AorB) => {
    obj.!!!AorB!!!.map(v => {
        console.log(v.value1 + v.value2)
    })
}
```

As you can see I currently replaced the part of where to decide if to call A or B with !!!AorB!!! as this is the part I am having issues with.

Is it possible to map the array elements of either a or b deepending on if either "a" or "b" is passed to the function as a string.

**Expected behavior**

When calling the function like this: `myFunction("a")` I expect the console to log:

```
a11a12
a21a22
a31a32
```

And the same with the values specified in b when calling `myFunction("b"()`

Comment: use obj[AorB].map(...) in your function

Comment: You can do `obj[a||b].map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **array syntax** to access objects values.

```js
const obj = {
  a: [{
      value1: "a11",
      value2: "a12"
    },
    {
      value1: "a21",
      value2: "a22"
    },
    {
      value1: "a31",
      value2: "a32"
    }
  ],
  b: [{
      value1: "b11",
      value2: "b12"
    },
    {
      value1: "b21",
      value2: "b22"
    },
    {
      value1: "b31",
      value2: "b32"
    }
  ]
};

const myFunction = (obj, AorB) => {
  // use the array syntax
  return obj[AorB].map(v => {
    return v.value1 + v.value2
  })
}

console.log('a:', myFunction(obj, 'a'))
console.log('b:', myFunction(obj, 'b'))
```